# AttributeError: module 'tensorly' has no attribute 'decomposition'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, module, attributeerror, tensorly

I’m using a package (tensorly) on python where I don't have access to all the modules.

For example if I try to use the 'decomposition' module :

- python version: 3.9.12
- tensorly version : 0.7

I run :

```
pip3 install tensorly
python3 main.py
```

main.py :

```
### imports ###
  
import tensorly

### tensor decomposition ###

cp = tensorly.decomposition.CP(n)
```

output :

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorly' has no attribute 'decomposition'
```

PS: When I go to /.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorly there is the module decomposition and when I print my sys.path there is the path for this same site-packages.

I have the **same problem with another package** (cobrapy) **and on other different machines** with other versions of python (3.6)

**Update :**

Now I have the exact same problem with scikit-learn:

```
from sklearn.preprocessingcessing import StandardScaler
```

Output :

```
No module named 'sklearn.preprocessingcessing'
```

Even if this package worked really well before (no error with .preprocessingcessing), this error popped out randomly today...

Answer (score 0):

You have to first import the submodule you want to use if it isn't loaded by default (you can check the `__init__.py` file to see what modules are imported by default).

In other words, just first import `decomposition`:

```
import tensorly
import tensorly.decomposition
```

Or directly import the decomposition methods you want to use:

```
from tensorly.decomposition import CP
```

You also have a typo in your Scikit-Learn example.